# Connecting to the server machine 'wsbeta.fedex.com' failed

Tags: c#, fedex

I want to start using Fedex web service, so I downloaded the sample code putted in the site "Fedex.com" for developers. But the folowing error occured:

> Unable to automatically step into the server. Connecting to the server
>   machine 'wsbeta.fedex.com' failed. This may be because the remote
>   computer does not exist or a firewall may be preventing communication
>   to the remote computer

it occured at this line:

```
ProcessShipmentReply reply = service.processShipment(request);
```

I use C#

Thank you,

Comment: Have you tried pinging the server? It's possible that it could have gone down. I'm not sure if any firewall on your end would block pings, though.

Comment: Thank you for reply, pinging wsbeta.fedex.com returns Request timed out

Comment: I just tested it, and it looks like the server is down. I know Amazon's AWS was suffering an outage this weekend; if Fedex used AWS for this server, that might be the issue. I'd suggest checking Fedex's website to see if there's any information about the outage, and contact them if you don't find anything.

Comment: I am still getting that same error, Any thoughts please

Comment: It still appears down from my end. Since I'm not familiar with their API, I'm not sure how much I can help you. You may want to visit their technical support page. You'll find the link on the left side of [their developer page.](http://www.fedex.com/us/developer/)

Comment: I fixed the problem,
It occurred because I did not put the correct Account number in this line:

request.RequestedShipment.ShippingChargesPayment.Payor.ResponsibleParty.AccountNumber = "client's account number";

Thank you James, 

Best Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed the problem,
It occurred because I did not put the correct Account number in this line:

request.RequestedShipment.ShippingChargesPayment.Payor.ResponsibleParty.AccountNumber = "client's account number";

Thank you James,

Best Regards